# Donut orientation by mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to figure out how to get this code to work so that the donut "follows" the cursor, however there is some trouble with the Y axis. The edges of the canvas look fine, but as soon as the cursor gets to the center, the donut starts spinning like hell. Is there any way to limit the rotation? And is it possible to rotate the donut itself, not the camera, because it seems wrong to me, but that's all I could find so far.

Here the code I have:

```js
let torusRotationY = 0

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL)
  torusRotationY = HALF_PI // Разворачиваем пончик на 90 градусов
}

function draw() {
  background(0)
  orbitControl()
  const targetX = mouseX - width / 2
  const targetY = mouseY - height / 2
  const targetZ = 0
  const distance = 400
  const target = createVector(targetX, targetY, targetZ)
  const cameraPosition = target.copy().normalize().mult(-distance)
  camera(cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y, cameraPosition.z)
  push()
  normalMaterial()
  rotateY(torusRotationY)
  torus(80, 45)
  pop()
  torusRotationY = atan2(targetX, distance) + HALF_PI
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.8.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you asked for, but this will 'look' at the cursor. I added some offset to the `targetZ` variable and inversed it in the `target` vector. Also the whole pop(), push(), rotateY() and `torusRotationY` was not necessary for it. Hope it helps.

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL)
}

function draw() {
    background(0)
    orbitControl()
    const targetX = mouseX - width / 2
    const targetY = mouseY - height / 2
    const targetZ = 100
    const distance = 400
    const target = createVector(targetX, targetY, -targetZ)
    const cameraPosition = target.copy().normalize().mult(-distance)
    camera(cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y, cameraPosition.z)
    normalMaterial()
    torus(80, 45)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.8.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Or, with the donut rotation instead of camera..

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL)
}

function draw() {
    background(0)
    orbitControl()
    const targetX = mouseX - width / 2
    const targetY = mouseY - height / 2
    const targetZ = 100
    const target = createVector(-targetX, -targetY, targetZ).normalize()
    camera(width / 2, 0, 0)
    push()
    normalMaterial()
    rotateY(HALF_PI - target.x)
    rotateX(target.y)
    torus(80, 45)
    pop()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.8.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```